# Spring Boot Injection? Get access to environment

Tags: java, spring, selenium, spring-mvc, gradle

I am currently working with webdriver extensions, which should use the yml config file from the module, so I try to get the environment injected. (I am even not sure whether this is called "injection")

So there is a ChromeSettings class which will be called by webdriver extensions to set the capabilities:

```
public class ChromeSettings extends DesiredCapabilities {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChromeSettings.class);

    public ChromeSettings() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);

        try {
            int test = ApplicationContextUtils.getEnvironment().getProperty("webdriver.screensize.width", Integer.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }

        setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    }
}
```

The webdriver extensions is not aware of any spring boot stuff, so I need to access to the environment somehow.

I already tried a bunch of annotation and read a lot about spring boot, but now I am totally confused and do not understand that spring boot annotation magic stuff.. I even can't find the stackoverflow question again, where I found this:

```
public class ApplicationContextUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        appContext = applicationContext; // never got executed
    }

    public static Environment getEnvironment() {
        return appContext.getEnvironment();
    }
}
```

`getEnvironment()` throws a null pointer exceptions because `setApplicationContext(..)` never got called by spring boot, so that appContext is null.

Can anyone give me a hint how I can get access to environment or to tell spring to execute the ApplicationContextUtils?

Comment: Is your class ApplicationContextUtils  a spring bean (@Component, @Service, @Configuration). If so Just Autowire Environment

Comment: Yuck... mutable statics (aka global variables)

Comment: I added @Component to ApplicationContextUtils, but appContext was still null. If I simply autowire: Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...) less... (Strg+F1) 
Checks that autowired members are defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...)